# Count numbers of records for member id

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

I am working on a little project for one of my customer. Basically I want to count the number of invoice per member ID. Each row of my tblinvoice has a column called member_id.

I have a gridview setup and stuff but I really have no clue how to count them.

like :

```
SELECT * FROM tblinvoices WHERE member_id=@membered
```

what would be the correct MySQL CMD?

Cheers,

Pierre

Comment: `SELECT count(*) as totalno FROM tblinvoices WHERE member_id=@membered`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT count(*) as total FROM tblinvoices WHERE member_id=@membered
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Count` in your sql query to get the ouptut....

```
SELECT count(*) as tt FROM tblinvoices WHERE member_id=@membered
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT count(member_id) as total FROM tblinvoices WHERE member_id=@membered

Answer (score 0):

@Krish R comment should work.
But if what you want is to get a list of all members (you said sth about a gridview...), and for each of them, get the number of  invoices:

```
SELECT member_id, count(*) as totalno
FROM tblinvoices 
GROUP BY member_id
```